# SaltStack: Ordering of States

Tags: salt-stack

My sls file looks like this:

## init.sls

```
include:
  - .packages
  - .user_and_group
```

## packages.sls

```
monitoring_packages:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - git
```

## user_and_group.sls

```
monitoring__group:
  group.present:
    - name: myuser
```

For some strange reason the state `monitoring__group` from the include "user_and_group" get executed before installing `git`.

## Question

How can I tell salt to install the packages first?

Answer (score 0):

## init.sls (unchanged)

```
include:
  - .packages
  - .user_and_group
```

## packages.sls (unchanged)

```
monitoring_packages:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - git
```

## user_and_group.sls (added require)

```
monitoring__group:
  group.present:
    - name: myuser
  require:
    - sls: packages
```

## Docs

I found the answer here: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#require-an-entire-sls-file

> As of Salt 0.16.0, it is possible to require an entire sls file.

## One question remains

This solves my problem. But one question remains: Why did salt execute the first version (see question) not in the top-to-bottom order? If you know it, please leave a comment.

Comment: please run `salt-master   -l debug`  and save the output for inspection. Post it to https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues  if the master and minion version are the latest version and tally.